# Prevent users from changing post status

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

The scenario is this:

An agent enters the post data (custom post), but can only do a pending for review or change the visibility of the post. He cannot change the post status manually.

I have achived the pending for review, but I cannot hide the "Status: published/pending etc. Edit". How is it possible (if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code where it's should be (plugin/functions.php/mu-plugin) - simple "hide" method using css.

```
add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php',     'hide_publishing_block_using_css');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'hide_publishing_block_using_css');
function hide_publishing_block_using_css(){
    echo '<style>#misc-publishing-actions{display:none;}</style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually though, I need the visibility part, but it seems that I'd have to change the javascript also because each time you press the cancel from visibility it reenables the Status bit.